# FFMPEG filters missing after upgrade to 4.0

Tags: ffmpeg

I built a statically linked binary of FFMPEG-3.4.4 from source. When I attempt to list the available filters in this binary, I get the following output.

`% ffmpeg -filters
ffmpeg version 3.4.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.1.2 (GCC) 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)
  configuration: --prefix=/local/workspace/src/FFmpeg/build/private/install --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-encoder=vorbis --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-static --disable-protocol=hls --disable-demuxer=hls --disable-decoder=prores --disable-decoder=prores_lgpl --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --disable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Filters:
  T.. = Timeline support
  .S. = Slice threading
  ..C = Command support
  A = Audio input/output
  V = Video input/output
  N = Dynamic number and/or type of input/output
  | = Source or sink filter
 ... abench            A->A       Benchmark part of a filtergraph.
 ... acompressor       A->A       Audio compressor.
 ... acopy             A->A       Copy the input audio unchanged to the output.
 ... acrossfade        AA->A      Cross fade two input audio streams.
 ... acrusher          A->A       Reduce audio bit resolution.
 T.. adelay            A->A       Delay one or more audio channels.
 ... aecho             A->A       Add echoing to the audio.
 ... aemphasis         A->A       Audio emphasis.
 ... aeval             A->A       Filter audio signal according to a specified expression.
 T.. afade             A->A       Fade in/out input audio.
 ... afftfilt          A->A       Apply arbitrary expressions to samples in frequency domain.
 .S. afir              AA->A      Apply Finite Impulse Response filter with supplied coefficients in 2nd stream.
 ... aformat           A->A       Convert the input audio to one of the specified formats.
 ... agate             A->A       Audio gate.
 ... ainterleave       N->A       Temporally interleave audio inputs.
 ... alimiter          A->A       Audio lookahead limiter.
 ... allpass           A->A       Apply a two-pole all-pass filter.
 ... aloop             A->A       Loop audio samples.
 ... amerge            N->A       Merge two or more audio streams into a single multi-channel stream.
 T.. ametadata         A->A       Manipulate audio frame metadata.
 ... amix              N->A       Audio mixing.
 ..C anequalizer       A->N       Apply high-order audio parametric multi band equalizer.
 ... anull             A->A       Pass the source unchanged to the output.
 T.. apad              A->A       Pad audio with silence.
 ... aperms            A->A       Set permissions for the output audio frame.
 ... aphaser           A->A       Add a phasing effect to the audio.
 ... apulsator         A->A       Audio pulsator.
 ... arealtime         A->A       Slow down filtering to match realtime.
 ... aresample         A->A       Resample audio data.
 ... areverse          A->A       Reverse an audio clip.
 ... aselect           A->N       Select audio frames to pass in output.
 ... asendcmd          A->A       Send commands to filters.
 ... asetnsamples      A->A       Set the number of samples for each output audio frames.
 ...........`

I recently tried doing the same with the source code for FFMPEG-4.0.2, but it doesn't show me any of the above filters. I've used the same configure options as the ones used with FFMPEG-3.4.4.

`% ffmpeg -filters
ffmpeg version 4.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.1.2 (GCC) 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)
  configuration: --prefix=/local/workspace/src/FFmpeg/build/private/install --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-encoder=vorbis --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-static --disable-protocol=hls --disable-demuxer=hls --disable-decoder=prores --disable-decoder=prores_lgpl --disable-ffplay --disable-shared
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Filters:
  T.. = Timeline support
  .S. = Slice threading
  ..C = Command support
  A = Audio input/output
  V = Video input/output
  N = Dynamic number and/or type of input/output
  | = Source or sink filter
 ... abuffer           |->A       Buffer audio frames, and make them accessible to the filterchain.
 ... buffer            |->V       Buffer video frames, and make them accessible to the filterchain.
 ... abuffersink       A->|       Buffer audio frames, and make them available to the end of the filter graph.
 ... buffersink        V->|       Buffer video frames, and make them available to the end of the filter graph.`

Am I missing a configure option to have these filters available in 4.0?

Comment: Share the output of configure.

Answer (score 1):

So after about spending nearly a day on this I realized that the problem was with a `sed` command change introduced in the `configure` script in version 4.0. I was building the source on a machine that has a non-GNU version of `sed` installed and didn't support the '-E' option. I ended up replacing it with '-r'. The specific line where I made the change is this: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/configure#L3723

Comment: See http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7310. Add a comment with your OS / tool details.